# CRM - how to add the case number to appointments

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

On CRM in the appointments you can click on the regarding tab to open up that appointments Case details.

Is it possible to add the CASE number for that appointment to the appointments page. Reason being every time I want to see the case number I need to click on regarding tab and open up another webpage.

Would be nice to just have the case number appear on the appointment page, anyway on the page is fine.

Is this possible?

thanks

Comment: Is the appointment created from the CASE form (through a subgrid/associated view) ? You could use mappings.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Alex and Disagree with Darren, although a plugin would get the job done it seems very excessive for what you are trying to accomplish.

The best way to do this between entities is to use the mapping fields between entity relationships however i don't believe CRM allows this between case and appointment in which case i would create a workflow.

Create a workflow on appointment firing on create or on-change of the regarding field, pull the case number field from the case entity when regarding is on case. This workflow will fire every time this event happens however you can build some extra logic around it and if there isn't a case entity no data will be pulled through.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can write a plugin on create and/or update of the regarding field on Appointment.  Within this plugin you can check if the regarding field is populated and if so if the entity type is incident.  If it is, obtain the Case Number (using the `OrganizationService`) and set the value of a custom attribute on the triggering Appointment.

Add the custom attribute to the Appointment form.  Generally this kind of reference information goes in the header section but it's entirely up to you.  If you don't place it there make sure you mark it as read-only.

Depending on your use case you may also want to check in the plugin when the regarding field changes.  If the regarding is removed or changed you'll need to make sure you update the case number on the Appointment to reflect this.

Comment: I think it would be better to handle with javascript in the OnChange event so you can see the information in real time and don't make heavy logic just for a field.